# Show multi-selected itens when load a edit view

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-forms, crud

I'm doing a edit form for some data. I'm having problem to pass information to . As you can see in my view, I pass the data to form using "initial" dictionary.

**VIEWS.PY**

```
@login_required
def project_detail(request, project_id):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        project = get_object_or_404(Project, pk=project_id)
        form = ProjectDetailForm(project_id, request.POST, instance = project)        
        if form.is_valid():
            instance = form.save(commit=False)
            instance.client = Project.objects.get(pk=project_id).client
            form.save()
            messages.success(request,'Projeto modificado')
            return redirect('projects')
        else:
            messages.error(request,'Ocorreu um erro!')
    else:
        project = get_object_or_404(Project, pk=project_id)
        form = ProjectDetailForm(project_id, initial={'modal':project.modal,
                                                    'culture':project.culture,
                                                    'owner':project.owner,
                                                    'value':project.value,
                                                    'final_date':project.final_date,
                                                    'text':project.text,
                                                    'status':project.status,
                                                    'farm':project.farm.values()})
    return render(request,'project_detail.html',{'form':form})
```

But doing this, the data is not displaied in . Thinking here, ManyToManyField saves data in lists. I tried iterate this field but still not working and I guess thats not the best way to do this.

**MODELS.PY**

```
class Project(models.Model):
    modal_types = [('CUSTEIO AGRÍCOLA','Custeio Agrícola'),('CUSTEIO PECUÁRIO','Custeio Pecuário'),('INVESTIMENTO AGRÍCOLA','Investimento Agrícola'),('INVESTIMENTO PECUÁRIO','Investimento Pecuário'),('FGPP','FGPP')]
    status_opts = [('Análise','Análise'),('Desenvolvimento','Desenvolvimento'),('Processamento','Processamento'),('Liberação','Liberação'),('Finalizado','Finalizado'),('Cancelado','Cancelado'),('Suspenso','Suspenso')]
    farm = models.ManyToManyField(Farm, related_name='farm_name',verbose_name='Propriedade beneficiada')
    client = models.ForeignKey(Clients, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='project_client',default=None,null=True, verbose_name='Cliente')
    owner = models.ForeignKey(Owner, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='project_bidder',default=None,null=True, verbose_name='Proponente')
    warranty = models.ManyToManyField(Farm, related_name='project_warranty',default=None, verbose_name='Propriedade de garantia')
    modal = models.CharField(max_length=100,default=None,choices=modal_types, null=True, verbose_name='Tipo')
    culture = models.CharField(max_length=50,null=True, verbose_name='Cultura')
    status = models.CharField(max_length=50,null=True, verbose_name='Status', choices=status_opts)
    created_date = models.DateField(null=True, verbose_name='Data de criação')
    value = models.FloatField(max_length=10,null=True, verbose_name='Valor financiado')
    final_date = models.DateField(default=None,null=True, verbose_name='Fim do contrato')
    text = models.TextField(default=None,null=True, verbose_name='Observações')
```

**forms.py**

```
class ProjectDetailForm(ModelForm):
    
    class Meta:
        model = Project
        fields = ['status','owner', 'farm', 'warranty', 'modal', 'culture', 'value','final_date','text']

    def __init__(self, project_id, *args, **kwargs):
        client_id = Project.objects.get(pk=project_id).client
        super(ProjectDetailForm,self).__init__(*args,**kwargs)
        self.fields['value'].required = False
        self.fields['final_date'].required = False
        self.fields['text'].required = False
        self.fields['farm'].queryset = Farm.objects.filter(client=client_id)
        self.fields['warranty'].queryset = Farm.objects.filter(client=client_id)
        for field_name, field in self.fields.items():
            field.widget.attrs['class'] = 'form-control'
```

*Here all the fields with information, but in "select" nothing is selected, despite having data in the database*
[image]

Someone can help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you passing 'project_id' into your form class instance?  Try changing this:

```
form = ProjectDetailForm(project_id, request.POST, instance = project)
```

to this:

```
form = ProjectDetailForm(request.POST, instance = project)
```

and see if it helps.  Also in your form initialization, I'm not sure you're using the "initial=" values dictionary correctly.  Initial values are typically defaults applicable to the "create" view, not database records that it sounds like you want to see in an update view.  I think you want to pass in the instance of your database record there, something like:

```
    else:
        project = get_object_or_404(Project, pk=project_id)
        form = ProjectDetailForm(instance=project)
```

Also, you really don't need to write project object query twice in this view.  You can do something like:

```
def project_detail(request, project_id):
    project = get_object_or_404(Project, pk=project_id) # query this once here
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ProjectDetailForm(request.POST, instance=project)        
        if form.is_valid():
            instance = form.save(commit=False)
            instance.client = Project.objects.get(pk=project_id).client
            form.save()
            messages.success(request,'Projeto modificado')
            return redirect('projects')
        else:
            messages.error(request,'Ocorreu um erro!')
            # you probably want a redirect here as well
    else:
        form = ProjectDetailForm(instance=project)

    return render(request,'project_detail.html',{'form':form})
```

Finally, if you're trying to limit the choices from your ManyToMany field in the user's form, you can do so with something like this:

```
class ProjectDetailForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = YourModelName
        fields = ['farm']

        farm = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(
        queryset=Farm.objects.filter(some_field=some_criteria).order_by('some_field'),
        widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple)
```

More info about widgets on form classes [here in Django docs.](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/forms/widgets/)

Comment: thanks for the reply but that didn't work

Comment: Aw, sorry that didn't sort it.  Can you explain more what you mean by "in "select" nothing is selected, despite having data in the database" ?  Thanks.

Comment: This is an edit form, so when they are rendered, the entries load and display the data from the data table, so the user can edit it. As you can see in the image at the end of my question, all the entries have data, "<select multiple> the entries also have data, but they don't have any items selected as this selection has already been made previously.

Comment: I see what you're saying.  Let up update my answer.

Comment: It worked! Thanks man! But this way I don't send "project_id" to my form where I use it to filter data for SelectMultiple. I forgot to show my form code, sorry I'll edit the question

Comment: Glad to hear it!  Since it worked, could you kindly mark the answer as accepted?  The answer to your other issue is to define your queryset filter on your model form class.  I'll add an example.  I know how tricky and sometimes frustrating form instantiation can be!

Comment: I knew the way I was doing it wasn't the best practice. Your response and example helped me a lot.
Thanks again, man.

Comment: You're most welcome!